# Getting html content api with laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to develop an application get html content from certain urls and shows them in my own web app.

UI web application will be laravel 5.3 its ok. But the thing is key pointhere  that retrieves data from urls(read and parse html content of via url)
and writes it to postgresql db migth be developed within laravel also ?

Before I decide to create this post I feel had to make an web service in python and read url and writes to db and read them within laravel web application. Which one is better or more efficient? 
Besides them I also wonder that is possible develop such a web service in laravel

Comment: you can try http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ if you want to do it with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ixudra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl) package. It's powerful, easy to use and you will be free to do anything you want. You can also save results into database. Make sure php-curl module installed on your php before you use this package. there is a pacakge named **Guzzle** and you can use that package but it's a little bit complicated than **ixudra**.
when you get html content from requested urls. You can parse the content with [yangqi/htmldom](https://packagist.org/packages/yangqi/htmldom) package.